# How can i check if a specific website is open in a tab in browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, browser

I am trying to check if `example.com` is open in tab in browser. and then display a message to user accordingly.

How can i check with JavaScript or jquery that , 
if `example.com` is opened in a tab in browser.
is there way i can do it. i do not own `example.com`

Comment: You can't. That would be a serious violation of privacy.

Comment: You can't unless you're writing a browser extension.

Comment: @AndrewLi how ?

Comment: All Browsers use only Tab !

Comment: note: a browser extension could do this as mentioned above, but then you'll have to get people to install it - but why would people be interested in such an extension when all they need to do is look at what sites they have open in their own tabs?